# OAuth2 flow for Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-oauth, oauth-2.0

I am developing a Chrome extension which needs to get an OAuth 2 access token for a Google service. But I am not sure whether to use the Authorization Code Grant flow or the Implicit Grant flow.

In the Implicit grant flow, I get the access token directly. However, since we don't get a refresh token here, we'll have to request for an access token again here if it expires. Will this ask the user to authenticate my App again (by showing him authentication UI) or will the user be oblivious to it?

Answer (score 3):

My experience using [chrome.identity](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity) API for authorization tokens is: the first time an authorization is needed (when the extension is first installed), the user is presented an authentication UI to confirm.
Whenever the token expires and a new token is necessary, calling chrome.identity.getAuthToken won't display the authentication UI but fetch a new token directly (no user interaction is needed if access was previously granted).